# Image processing

Tags: android, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'd like to use some tools for image processing.
One of the requirments is ability to manipulate the image and change it by touch as it appen in the "Plastic Surgery" game by "Kaeria".
How it can be done? where can i find a lib that do so?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android OpenCV is pretty bad on documentation if you are planning to use the JAVA wrapper. I would suggest that you learn to use the inbuilt functions and structure of the API using a C++ implementation and then try to use the JAVA API. Also You could eventually run NATIVE code on the android platform using the NDK.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Android OpenCv for image processing.Check this [link](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)

Answer (score 0):

android opencv should helps. You can download the sdk from the [**Link**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.2/OpenCV-2.4.2-android-sdk.zip/download)
and the configurations available in this link [**opencv samples**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html#running-opencv-samples)